# SQL Server 2008 connecting to instance is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to deploy my database on a customer server

I tried this:

```
select @@servername
```

and I got this

```
`INCONCERTSERVER`
```

Then I tried to create this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAgentStatues]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    EXECUTE sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
    RECONFIGURE
    EXECUTE sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
    RECONFIGURE

    SELECT UserName, LoggedState, InteractionId, InteractionType    --<-- The columns required.
    FROM 
    OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI'
            ,'Server=INCONCERTSERVER;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=MMProDat'
            ,'EXECUTE dbo.[SupGetAgentsWithInteractions]')
END
```

I got this error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
>   Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

Could you help me please?

I am already using a windows admistrator accound and an administrator on the database

#### I am working remotely using remote desk top

Comment: I think your Server Configuration system stored procedures should be in a separate batch.

Comment: @M.Ali what do you mean please? I think that I need to set the servername and the instance name, right?

Comment: @M.Ali please check the upated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAgentStatues]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT UserName, LoggedState, InteractionId, InteractionType  
    FROM 
    OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI'
               ,'Server=INCONCERTSERVER;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=MMProDat'
               ,'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON;EXECUTE dbo.[SupGetAgentsWithInteractions]')
END
```

### Execute Proc

```
EXECUTE sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE
GO

EXECUTE sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE
GO

EXECUTE [dbo].[getAgentStatues]
GO
```

Comment: I already tried like your way but without creating two stored procedure. I exectued your first stored procedure manually, then I tried to execute your second stroed procedure but the same error message accures

Comment: the problem is yoru second stored procedure can't be created.

Comment: It would be nice to know if it helped or not?

Comment: the problem was in the servername, i typed server name of sql while I should have typed the server name (computer name)